# Java selecting an option when clicking specific position within JScrollPane

Tags: java, chat, jscrollpane

I have developed a chat room application in Java that allows users to broadcast messages to every online user. I want to develop a new functionality that will allow the user to click on one of the online users in order to have a private chat with him/her. For this purpose I have developed a scroll-able text area that will contain those online users.

I think I could set the coordinates of each position that the name will be located at, in the text area so then when a mouse button is clicked I will compare this position against a position of the name in the string output of array list that was passed from the server (i.e. [Adrian, Buddy, Bob]).

As I have mentioned before, I am using a scroll-able text area for showing the online list, therefore I am not entirely sure if this approach would work out once I scroll down the list and click one of the positions.

Perhaps you could recommend me another approach I could adapt, or clarify if this one would work.

Here is the image of my chat client:
[image: chat client]

Comment: This question is actually not about chat clients at all. It's about selecting an option from a scroll pane. You're using the wrong component I think.

Comment: You're right, I have changed the title to reflect your comment. Would you have any idea of what would be a good component that would allow me to keep my current functionality (i.e. scrolling through online list) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I have mentioned before, I am using a scroll-able text area for
>   showing the online list, therefore I am not entirely sure if this
>   approach would work out once I scroll down the list and click one of
>   the positions.

Working with Scrollable TextArea for selecting items and responding with it the way you described: it will just be a hazard. Use `JList` with `ListSelectionListener` instead.

**Tutorial Resource:**

1. [How to use List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
2. [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)